# Drupal 7: In Views, how could I order/sort in this manner?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Say for example I am printing name tags for thousands of content nodes in one content type called “Attendee.” Each of these nodes specifies a single "Attendee" for an event, (and their respective name tag). **Say these attendees also needed name tags printed out for their “friends” who are attending with them.** That is no problem—these “friends” obviously need their own node with the same fields to get their own name tag, so I distinguish that they are a “Friend of an Attendee” with a simple checkbox.

**Now here’s the sorting order / grouping problem:**  When rendering the view, I need these “friends of attendees” to appear “right after” the attendee they are going with. Is there a way for me to maybe create a new autocomplete text field to link these together and then have them output next to each other?

*p.s. I am technically using the Views PDF module, but it has the basic Views functions, so if it's possible with Views, it will probably be possible with this module.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to group these together, you have to have some way of linking friends to the attendees. You can do this by adding an entity reference field to the content type. See https://drupal.org/project/entityreference

here are the steps:

- from admin/structure/types select "manage fields" on your content type
- on the "manage fields" tab, click in "Add new field", and type in a label name. say "friend of"
- for "type", select "Entity Reference", and for now, choose "Autocomplete" for your widget
- click save

in the field edit tab:

- select Target Type: Node
- under Entity Selection, set Mode: Simple
- set Target bundles: ( your attendees type )
- click save
- go to admin/config/development/performance and clear all caches

You should now see an autocomplete field when you edit an attendee that you can use to set the friend relationship

Things normally get a bit complicated now, as you have to tell views about the relationship between attendees and their friends. If you want to keep this dead easy, you can set the primary attendees as their own "friend" ( who they are going with ) so that you can group them together easily with their companions, without having to worry about contexts, relationships, or any other fancy stuff.

Comment: thank you-- I added a Node Reference field but cannot seem to get the Views module to sort the friends of attendees right after the attendee they are going with. I've messed around with both entity references & node references alongside views relationships and cannot find a solution yet. Any tips?

Comment: If you've added the entity reference field to your view, and have it so that the friends of an attendee do group together, but not not with the main attendee, it's probably because you haven't set the main attendee's "friend of" field to themselves. Think of it like a grouping field, where it sorts everyone in a group together, so you have to add the main person to the group ( identified as associated with themselves ). My responses here will be a bit slow, as I am on vacation, on a borrowed laptop.

Comment: Dom Day, I really appreciate your help so far but here is what I have-- hope it helps: http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/8181/wtvy.png

Let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: to revise my last comment, I added one more screenshot (2nd to last): http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/4233/7w7h.png

Comment: Dom Day, I know we are both busy persons but I've been totally stuck on this issue and would really appreciate a few minutes of your time if that's possible. Here is my most recent configuration: http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9213/x7u.png PLEASE ask if you have any questions. Thanks & God bless